# QMF query about date format

Tags: sql, date

I have one column with the date format of `yyyy-mm-dd` and another with the format of `mm/dd/yyyy`. How can I change the second format to look like the first in QMF sql writing?

Comment: By not storing dates as strings...  there's a `date` format for a (very) good reason.

Comment: we didn't store it as a string, we need to replicate the format from one column to the other. how can we do that?

Comment: what database engine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can alter your table columns using an SQL command like this. I have specifically changed the column to a date format in the example

> ALTER TABLE `'Schema_Name'`.`'Table_Name'` 
>   CHANGE COLUMN `'Column_Name'` `'New_Column_Name'` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL;